# How to get an XML attribute value with Linq to XML?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm trying to get just the specific employee Id out of an XML file so that I can go look up some Groups the employee is associated with and then add those Groups as an element to the XML.

First I need the employeeId so I can then go look up some info and I'm not understanding how to get it. I'm guessing I'm not getting it because of all the nested nodes.

Here is the XML structure.

```
<CXIXML>
  <Directives>
    <Updates>
      <Emp tasEmpID="00123" lName="Doe" fName="John" empStatus="A" city="HDQ" />
      <Emp tasEmpID="00456" lName="Smith" fName="Jane" empStatus="A" city="HDQ" />
    </Updates>
  </Directives>
</CXIXML>
```

Here is what I tried but I'm not getting the ID.

```
private static void SetGroupAssociations(string xmlFile)
        {
            XElement xelement = XElement.Load(xmlFile);
            IEnumerable<XElement> employees = xelement.Elements();
            foreach (var employee in employees)
            {
                var employeeId = from e in employee.Descendants("Emp")
                                 select new
                                 {
                                     Id = e.Element("tasEmpID")
                                 };

                Console.WriteLine(employeeId);
            }
        }
```

Ultimately I need to end up with something like the following. So, any suggestions on how to add the new element after the specific employee node would be great but first I have at least get the employee so I can look up their groups.

```
<CXIXML>
  <Directives>
    <Updates>
      <Emp tasEmpID="00123" lName="Doe" fName="John" empStatus="A" city="HDQ" />
      <Group groupId="1">
      <Group groupId="5">
      <Group groupId="12">
      <Emp tasEmpID="00456" lName="Smith" fName="Jane" empStatus="A" city="HDQ" />
      <Group groupId="1">
    </Updates>
  </Directives>
</CXIXML>
```

Comment: Have you posted relevant xml data? Your C# code tries to get value from "sharpID" element, but there is no such attribute in your xml under `Emp` element.

Comment: Edited. There are a couple attributes that have the same value. I trimmed some attributes to cut down on the posted code.

Comment: Look at the answer I wrote you.

Comment: Have you considered to use XPath to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks similar than what you already had. Then within the foreach you can add sentences to your process.

```
var document = XDocument.Load(xmlFile);
var employees = document.Descendants("Emp");
foreach (var employee in employees)
{
    var employeeId = employee.Attribute("tasEmpID").Value;
    Console.WriteLine(employeeId);
}
```

I've put document in a separate variable, so that you'll be able to save your changes using this object.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your xml structure is not correct, what you describe the groups would be inside of each Emp, so I'm going to assume that.

To get an employee by an attribute you can do the following:

```
 XElement xelement = XElement.Load(xmlFile);
 var emp=xelement.Descendants("Emp")
                 .FirstOrDefault(e=>(string)e.Attribute("tasEmpID")=="00456");
```

Now to add the groups to the current employee, just use `Add` method:

```
emp.Add(groups.Select(g=>new XElement("Group",new XAttribute("groupId",g.Id))));
```

This is assuming `groups` variable is an `IEnumerable<Group>`

Comment: I marked derloopkat as the answer because it did what I was asking for in the question, however, ultimately I might have to use a variation of this since I will probably have to change up the way I was tackling this issue. I might have to use a list of employees, find their node based on the attribute, and then add the group node.

Comment: I might have to change up everything including going back to XmlDocument instead of Linq to XML. Since there are some conditional checking I have to do I was initially using Linq to XML to write out the employees and then loading the file to look at the groups. With XmlDocument I can write out each node individually. It can probably be done with Linq to XML as well but I haven't found anything and I have to have this finished up today.

Comment: I don't see what are the issues you found adding elements using Linq2XML.It's pretty simple. If you like add a new question with you current problem and let me know to take a look